# Azure Active Directory - Validate the claims

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD for Grant a native or web app permissions to a web API. I am generating the token from the native application (UWP or IOS) and authorizing the Web API. While testing the api using the postman call, I am able to use a token in different machines and able to call the api method (without any 401 unauthorized error). How to avoid this scenario? My question is how to prompt user to always register their devices? or how to validate the device specific tokens?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to prompt user to always register their devices?

I assume that you're using client grant flow to obtain access token via Postman. With client grant flow, the you will get access token directly without user to sign-in. Also, Azure AD endpoint doesn't support such claim for validating devices.

Since you've get access token and you use it in other devices. This means that you just can access the resource via the device.

> how to validate the device specific tokens

Azure AD doesn't support this kind claim or use things like Device ID to authentication. Generally, you shouldn't expose the access token to other devices. If you're using access token in other devices, it means that the device should be under your control. You need to accept this fact.

What I suggest is you can use [authorization code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code) and don't transfer token across devices.

Comment: I am creating application like [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-windows-store) . I am generating the token from the native client application . For testing purpose, I am getting that token from the client and testing the api from the postman call inf different machine. I didnt get the unauthorized message since the token is generated from one machine. Please let us know whether the code grant flow work in this scenario?

Comment: @Ctech  Um... This sample is using code grant flow.  I didn't know you're using this sample and how did you use Postman to test your API. But it doesn't matter. What I want to say is that, since you can obtain the token ,you just can use the token as you want. If you use the token in another device, it just can be used. Additional, I really don't understand why you use one token on different devices. If it is just a test, it can be understood.

Comment: This is for testing purpose. If someone knows my token and they can use it from their machine and able to access the api. Then he will get all the information from the api. Please let me know if there is any other to do this?.

Comment: Actually, it's hard to say whether others can get your token. It's an issue about Network securtiy. So, that's too board to discuss here. The token are transfered with Https and be encoded. Generally, other people cannot get it.:-)